# What is the name for the view that manages the iPhone home screen?

Tags: iphone, uiview, homescreen

My google-fu is failing here. I'm looking for the name of the `UIView` (or whatever it is) that handles several pages, with those little glowing dots indicating which page you're on.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650437/iphone-uiscrollview-with-uibuttons-how-to-recreate-springboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on coneybeare's brief description, there is no special control that does the pages, it is simply a UIView within a UIScrollView with code to 'lock' the scrolling to certain spots (pages). The UIPageControl is simply a display of which position the scrollview is currently locked to.

A perfect example is Apple's sample code/demo here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/index.html

Comment: Most of the "code to 'lock' the scrolling" is the UIScrollView's pagingEnabled property. Most of the rest of the code in that sample is to 1) load the views in the scroll view, and 2) to keep the scroll view's offset and the page control's currentPage in synch.

Comment: Accepted for the sample code. I probably would've hunted around for a while to find the `pagingEnabled` property.

Answer (score 4):

`UIScrollView` is the name of the view with pages
`UIPageControl` is what you connect to it to add the dots