# UIScrollView only works if the child views aren't hit

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uibutton, drag

I have a scroll view that doesn't scroll right, I've simplified the code for below. 
It draws the view and some horizontal buttons that i add more stuff to in the real code. 
If you drag the whitespace between the buttons the view scrolls. If you happen to put your finger on a button, it won't scroll. 
After a related suggestion, I tried to add the delaysContentTouches = YES line, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. 
[UIScrollview with UIButtons - how to recreate springboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650437/iphone-uiscrollview-with-uibuttons-how-to-recreate-springboard)

What am I doing wrong?
TIA,
Rob

Updated the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    l = [self landscapeView];
    [self.view addSubview:l];
    [l release];    
}

- (UIScrollView *) landscapeView {
    // LANDSCAPE VIEW
    UIScrollView *landscapeView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 325)];
    landscapeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    landscapeView.delaysContentTouches = YES;
    NSInteger iMargin, runningY, n;
    iMargin = 3;
    runningY = iMargin;

    for (n = 1; n <= 38; n++) {
        //add day labels
        UIButton *templabel = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(iMargin,runningY,320 - ( 2 * iMargin),20)];
        templabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [landscapeView addSubview:templabel];
        [templabel release];
        runningY = runningY + 30;
    }
    landscapeView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( 320, runningY);

    return landscapeView; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't duplicate your results; when I create a scrollView and add buttons, scrolling is still active even when doing a touch-down on the button.  Are you setting any other UIScrollView properties, or subclassing any methods, that aren't showing up in your simplified code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one thing that's going on is that the getter for landScapeView is a complicated constructor...so every time you do [self landscapeView] or self.landscapeView, you're creating a whole new UIScrollView and operating on that.

I'd try something like this in your .h file:

```
@interface MyClass: MyParent {
  UIScrollView *landscapeView;
}

@property (retain) UIScrollView *landscapeView;
```

...and this in your .m file:

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize landscapeView;

(void)viewDidLoad 
{ l = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 325)] autorelease];
  [self.view addSubview:self.landscapeView]; [l release]; 
  landscapeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  landscapeView.delaysContentTouches = YES;
   NSInteger iMargin, runningY, n;
  iMargin = 3;
  runningY = iMargin;
  for (n = 1; n <= 38; n++) { //add day labels 
       UIButton *templabel = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(iMargin,runningY,320 - ( 2 * iMargin),20)];
       templabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; 
       [landscapeView addSubview:templabel]; 
       [templabel release]; runningY = runningY + 30; 
  } 
  landscapeView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( 320, runningY);
```

}

Comment: Thanks Greg, I'll try that. I agree it's poorly constructed, old code I think. Do you think that this will fix the scrolling problem?
Rob

Comment: Ok, made the change. Still have the issue with the buttons not being clickable. Should i try to make a mini app of the problem and upload it? I'm at a loss.