# ‘static‘ UIButton ontop UIScrollview?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton, touches

I want to achieve a rather simple effect. A scrollView and a static button above it.
So far not problem. Unfortunately a problem occurs if I want to scroll the view "trough" the button. So start dragging inside the button will effect the button, not the scroll view.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Thanks a lot!

I think this approach won't work because touchesBegan is deprecated in UIScrollView … (Is this info true?)

Not the solution :-)

```
@implementation MySuperButton

+ (id)buttonWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    return [[[self alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self == [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        NSLog(@"initWithFrame");
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"[self nextResponder]: %@", [self nextResponder]);
}

@end
```

Unfotunately this does not work, yet. I think the next responder is a my UIView not my UIScrollView. Any ideas?

If my viewcontroller which is the nextResponder, passes the touches to the scrollView, nothing happens aswell.

Comment: When you say above do you mean vertically or on top of?

Comment: I meant on top of it. sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: You need to specify what behavior you want. Eiko asked you this on April 4th and you've been online leaving comments since then, but yet you still haven't answered.

Comment: @rdesign Did you solve this problem? Most of the answers authors did not understand you right...

Answer (score 12):

Add the button not to the scroll view but to its parent view, and everything should work just fine. Touches on the button directly will get delivered to the button, and touches on the background (scroll view) will get delivered to the scroll view.

As the button isn't a subview of the scroll view it won't move with the background (which I suppose you mean with *static*).

Comment: Does this solve your problem or did I misread your question? What should happen in case of touching the button (scroll or not)?

Comment: +1 This is correct if he doesn't want it to scroll, but maybe he wants it to. I don't understand why he still haven't specified which behavior he is after.

Answer (score 1):

I never played alot with the touch events and such, but i'll try to help with my basic understanding anyway.

Try setting the button's [exclusiveTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW33) to NO. Not sure, but maybe enableMultitouch to YES as well.

If that doesn't work i'd try maybe subclassing UIButton, overriding the touch events and passing them to [self nextResponder] before/after [super touchEventX:]?

Comment: Thanks for your help. This sounds kind of complicated to me, as I never played a lot with touch events, too :-) I'll give it a try.

Comment: @resign i'd try also doing the same with touchesEnded and touchesMoved. also did setting exclusiveTouch to NO change anything?

Comment: @rdesign try scrollView.delaysContentTouches = YES; scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;

Here's a question that was asked here about the same thing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650437/iphone-uiscrollview-with-uibuttons-how-to-recreate-springboard

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to scroll through the button or not?

> So start dragging inside the button will effect the button, not the scroll view.

It's not clear if that's the behavior you want or the behavior you're trying to change.

If it's the former Eiko's answer is correct and if it's the later you should add the button as a subview of the scroll view and update its frame whenever `scrollViewDidScroll:` is called. I've never tried this, but it works in theory.

Answer (score 0):

Move the whole Scroll View down by the height of your Button and shrink it's height by the same amount. Then put your Button above the the Scroll View - so it's not a child of the Scroll View.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I described it the wrong way. I meant on top of it. So the button should be on top of the scrollview. The scrollview should still recognize the touches, the button receives. The button should only fire on touchdowninside.

Comment: So you want one touch to effect two different objects? That sounds like a bad interface idea... what's the reason for the button?

Comment: I want to make a menu. something like there's a bottle of wine(the button). you can slide the background to choose wheather you want to find a location inside or outside to drink it (get the idea?)

Answer (score 0):

If you add simple button in a **view** then if u touch on button. it will calls Action of it.

Sameway

If you add simple button in a **ScroolView** then if u touch on button. it will calls Action of it.

**And if u touch on the empty area of scroolview then the delegate methods are called of UIScrollView.**

***If you put your finger on button and Drag it will obviosly effect on the scrollview. scrollview will drag 100%***