# How do I pass delayed scroll gestures from a UIButton inside of a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a UIScrollView that contains several UIButtons. Each button is wired up to take an action when the user inputs a touch up event, so they are able to place their finger on the button and it will not be selected until it is raised. Currently, if I made a swipe gesture to scroll the UIScrollView quickly, then the scroll view moves as expected even if the gesture happens directly over a UIButton. HOWEVER, if I hold my finger down too long on a UIButton (about 1 second), the UIScrollView will no longer recognize the gesture and will not be able to scroll until the finger is lifted up.

I am wondering if their is a way to always have the UIScrollView recognize the scroll gesture? Note that this is not an issue if I touch the UiScrollView in a location without a UIButton - it then scrolls as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this here: [UIScrollview with UIButtons - how to recreate springboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650437/iphone-uiscrollview-with-uibuttons-how-to-recreate-springboard)

Essentially, I had to extend UIScrollView and override touchesShouldCancelInContentView, having it always return YES.

Answer (score 0):

It may worth a try to let your `UIButton` respond to `UIControlEventTouchDown` (maybe with an empty action). I'm not sure if this will work, but conceptually I think it should let the `UIButton` capture the touch immediately.

(Also make sure you don't enable `delaysContentTouches` on your scrollview.)

Comment: Actually, I need it to respond to UIControlEventTouchUp. I don't want the button to respond immediately and I want the button event to be canceled if the touch input changes to a scroll event.

Comment: No I mean, put an empty `IBAction` for `UIControlEventTouchDown` just to hijack the touch from being sent to the scrollview, and then implement whatever you want the button to do in `UIControlEventTouchUp`.