# UIScrollView Not Scrolling Properly after add other controls

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uiscrollview

I am Creating a Tabbar Application, In 3rd Tabbar i have some products showing in CollectionView, where user will select one product it will take user to a Form. until here it working perfect.Because my form fields are many so i decide to use UIScrollView control to show all fields filled by the user. When I add any control like UIImageView or Label or Button  the ScrollView is not scrolling. I need the size `[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1100)];` , Without any control the ScrollView scrolling fully without any problem. After Adding any control the ScrollView not scrolling properly. what i have to do so the scrollView will scroll fully after i add any control. Am using Storyboard and UINavigationController for navigation.

```
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1100)];
[scroller setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"OrderBackround.png"]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `UISCrollView's` property 
`setDelaysContentTouches` to YES.
More explanation you will find
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/658893/1570343)